# Photoshop stacking clipping masks

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, clipping-mask

Photoshop 2020

So, can I somehow stack clipping masks non-destructively? Say I have 3 layers. I want Layer1 to clip Layer2, and Layer3 clip them both.

Right now if you try to stack it, all the layers are going to be clipped by the root layer and groups don't seem to have clipping masks either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a clipping masks and smart objects.

Turn Layer 1 into a smart object and have it clipped by Layer 3. Open Layer 1 smart object and place Layer 2 and have it clipped by Layer 1.

Main document Layers Panel

[image: Main layers]

Layer 1 smart object Layers Panel

[image: Smart object]

Final image

[image: final image example]

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Just what I needed. Gotta wait 4 minutes to mark it as answer damn that was quick